# 'dict' object is not callable error - when I'm not using any 'dict's in networkx

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I'm using Python to work with networkx and draw some graphs.

I ran into a problem raising:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

on this line of code:

```
set_node_color(num, list(Graph.node()))
```

I searched to find that this error is raised when I'm using a variable name `dict`.

The problem is, I'm not using any variables with the name `dict`, nor am I using any dictionary types anywhere in the code.
In case it's necessary, printing the type of `Graph` gives `<class 'networkx.classes.digraph.Digraph'>`.

I also tried printing the type for `Graph.node()` only to receive the same error, telling me `'dict' object is not callable`.
So I suspect `Graph.node()` to be a `dict` type variable, but using `(Graph.node()).items()` raises the same `TypeError`.

Any help or advices would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: You need to include a larger code snippet. It is hard to tell what is going on with the code you've provided.

Comment: Check the type of just `Graph.node` (without `()`)

Comment: Do you probably have a traceback and a bit more code?

Comment: When in doubt, read (and include) full backtrace. It does not only tell you what happened, but also where incl. whole context. You can also run the script in a debuger (`python -m pdb ...`) which lets you poke around the failed script and learn more about what was going on around the time it died.

Comment: I didn't know Python has a debugger, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `Graph.node` is a `dict` object, so `Graph.node()` is not callable.